Disable Automatically Tracked Events on Firebase Analytics
On Firebase Analytics for Android, certain events like screen_view or session_start are automatically tracked.
Since I wanted to send additional parameters with screen_view, I added the following line to AndroidManifest.xml to disable automatic tracking:
<meta-data android:name="google_analytics_automatic_screen_reporting_enabled" android:value="false" />

Is there a similar way to manually track session_start with custom parameters, for example?

Your code is not showing, btw.
